# exporting lists in python as excel rows, why it just export first row?

Tags: python, arrays, excel, pandas, list

I try to export 2 specific lines from multiple (.txt) files in path as excel rows, and exporting them into excel files.. But the (.xlsx) file just containing first row (just exported lines of one text file).

```
import pandas as pd
import linecache
import xlsxwriter as xlsw
import os
import glob

directory=('C:\Users\john\Desktop')
os.chdir(directory)
files=glob.glob('*.txt')

for filename in files:
 name = linecache.getline(filename,5)
 id = linecache.getline(filename,13)
 info = [name,id]
 final_list = []
 for i in info:
  final_list.append(i.strip())
 print (final_list)
 df = pd.DataFrame(final_list)
 df = df.transpose()
 writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
 df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='welcome',startrow=1,startcol=0, header=False, index=False)
 writer.save()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
import pandas as pd
import linecache
import xlsxwriter as xlsw
import os
import glob

directory=('test')
os.chdir(directory)
files=glob.glob('*.txt')

final_list = []
for filename in files:
 name = linecache.getline(filename,5)
 id = linecache.getline(filename,13)
 info = [name,id]
 final_list.append([i.strip() for i in info])
print (final_list)
df = pd.DataFrame(final_list)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='welcome',startrow=1,startcol=0, header=False, index=False)
writer.save()
```

Comment: thanks a lot, its work but one last thing: can i  print the lines for (.txt) files horizontally instead of vertically? i want the file lines in row, the second file in new row, the third...

Comment: Yes, just remove df = df.transpose().